# Best Strategy for predicting a Calendar with daily routines

Tags: machine-learning, scikit-learn, machine-learning-model

I have a data-sheet with calendar entries of a single person which consists out of every-day routines such as sleeping, eating, working, body care, ...

In total, there are about 40 different activities with an avg of 15 activities per day being tracked by the person over the total time-span of 12 months.

Each entry basically consists out of a string (activity name) and 2 timestamps (start and end). Also worth to mention is that there are no overlapping activities. Rather they mostly stick right next to each other (if one stops at 15:00, the next one most likely either starts at 15:00 or a couple of minutes afterwards).

Based on the original data, I generated custom columns (minute, hour, day, month, year, week, weekday, holiday) based on the start date and end date.

The goal is to use scikit-learn to make a model based on the data of the last 12 months and then predict the calendar for up to 3 days - So if there is data until June 10, the script should predict June 11,12,13.

My question now is: What is the best strategy to tackle this problem? I'm not aware of any models with multi-input and multi-output where I directly get a list of non-overlapping calendar entries so I thought about 2 other ways:

**Rasterize all entries into 15min blocks**. The idea is to create 15min blocks showing minute 0 until 1440 for each day and then generating an entry for each 15min block an activity is running. So this strategy uses the activity, start_block (15min block on daily basis), weekday, day, month, year as input and the activity as output. I can then create 3 arrays with (1440/15) elements and use the trained model to fit those 3 future days.

**Calculating Future Activity based on Event Relations**. Most activities typically follow other activities (E.g. Wake up and go to the bathroom, have a shower after sport, ...). The idea with this approach is to use the activity, start minute (daily basis), weekday as input (I therefore modified the input sheet to have one column showing the following activity) and get the next activity and duration as output. This way I can give the last entry of the data sheet and incrementally call fit to predict the upcoming activities one by one.

While the first approach generally gives good times but a bad segmentation, the second one results in a good segmentation but very bad timing of the actual activities. So I ask:

Are there better strategies other than this or Am I on the right track and rather should investigate my scikit implementation?